# Does the decision function in scikit-learn return the true distance to the hyperplane?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Does the decision function return the *actual* distance to the hyperplane for each sample as stated [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function). Or do you have to the extra calculation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074239/sklearn-getting-distance-of-each-point-from-decision-boundary). Which method should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the actual distance. And depends on the case, you may (linear kernel) or may not (non-linear kernel) be able to convert that to an actually distance. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030253/decision-values-in-libsvm#11041503) is another good explanation. Not matter what, yes you have to take [that extra step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074239/sklearn-getting-distance-of-each-point-from-decision-boundary#32077408) if you want the **actual distance**.

Comment: Does this also impy the margin distance is normalized to 1?

Comment: @gman9732 According to the [mathematical formulation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#mathematical-formulation), yes. And that's why for `LinearSVC` you can use `np.linalg.norm()` to get the actual distance.

Comment: Does the mean the margin distance *is* 1. And I am able to determine if a point is in the margin by seeing if its distance is < 1?

Comment: Yes in general, but not exactly. As you can see from the [mathematical formulation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#mathematical-formulation), the model is solved so that the margin is greater or equal to 1-ζi. Therefore, the margin distance from you training points may be slightly less (depends on ζi) than 1. And a point in the margin should have a normalized distance less than 1-ζi rather than 1.